# What GLSL file extension does Xcode recognise?

Tags: xcode, glsl, file-extension

Note: This question is specifically about Xcode. There are other questions about GLSL file extensions, for example: [What is the correct file extension for GLSL shaders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432838/what-is-the-correct-file-extension-for-glsl-shaders)

I've been using `.glsl` for GLSL code files but I've also tried these: `.glslv`, `.glslf,` `.vsh`, `.fsh`, `.vert`, and `.frag` - but I always have to manually go and set the file type to "OpenGL Shading Language Source" after creating/adding the file to my project.

a) Is there an extension that Xcode will automatically recognise as GLSL source?

or...

b) Is there a way to tell Xcode to associate an extension of my choosing with the GLSL source file type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reason to believe that the answer to your (a) question is No.  I looked at the document type and exported UTI declarations in the Info.plist of Xcode 4.5.1.  It lists 4 extensions for fragment shaders, associated with the UTI org.khronos.glsl.fragment-shader: .fs, .fsh, .frag, .fragment.  There are similar extensions for vertex shaders and geometry shaders.  But if I add a file with any of these 4 fragment shader extensions to a project, Xcode just classes it as generic source code.

I'd bet that the answer to (b) is also No, but I can't prove it.